# static_assert that checks if template parameter type is accepted by another function

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, static-assert

I have a function template defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
Test &operator<<(const T &data)
{
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

As you can see, I print out to the console `data` using `std::cout`, which type is `std::ostream`. However, `T` may not be a type handled by `std::ostream::operator<<`.

That's why I'd like to add a `static_assert` to check whether `T` is accepted by the insertion operator or not. Currently, I must do a check for every type that `std::ostream::operator<<` accept:

```
template <typename T>
Test &operator<<(const T &data)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value ||
                  std::is_same<T, std::streambuf*>::value ||
                  ...
                  std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, "data type must be compliant to std::ostream::operator<< accepted types");

    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Is there a *type trait* that automatically do that? What would you do?

Comment: First off, you can't print a type. So, `std::cout << T << std::endl` is wrong in the first place. What you probably meant is `std::cout << data << std::endl;`. Second I don't see the point in this. If `T` isn't printable `std::cout` will complain and you'll get the error you want.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant `std::cout << data << std::endl` of course, my mind was probably elsewhere when I wrote it.

Comment: @GuiTeK Do you have any particular need to catch that error? If `operator<<` is not overloaded for `T`, the compilation will fail anyway (due to `static_assert` or overload resolution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want a `static_assert`? Is it acceptable to simply make the function not callable if the insertion isn't valid?

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(const T &data) -> decltype(std::cout << data, std::declval<Test&>())
{
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

If you really want a trait see [is_stream_insertable](https://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/source/HEAD:include/redi/printers.h#L1)

Comment: Undefined behavior here, for reaching the closing brace of a non-void function.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the pedantry, it was copied from the OP. Did you fail to notice it there? Twice?

Comment: You've also used the comma operator with a type, which is brokenness not in the original function.

Comment: I think you're capable of writing code to a higher standard than most people asking questions.

Comment: I don't know how to return `Test&` because that type isn't even in the OP's question, so I kept it as close as possible to the original (broken) example

Comment: Almost surely `return *this;`

Comment: Indeed it's `return *this;`. I forgot it, sorry. Added.